# Matlab Dsolve error using parameters

Tags: matlab, dsolve

I am trying to solve a set of differential equations on Matlab using `dsolve` command. I have three equations as defined below but instead of numerical coefficients, I have generic parameters like `lambda1`, `lambda2`, etc. and I want to get the results in terms of these parameters. The code is below:

```
    syms p0(s) p1(s) p2(s) lambda1 lambda2 mu1 mu2;
    eqn1=diff(p0)-1==-lambda1*p0-lambda2*p0+mu1*lambda2*p0/(s+mu2)+mu2*lambda1*p0/(s+mu1);
    eqn2=s*p1==lambda1*p0-mu2*p1;
    eqn3=s*p2==lambda2*p0(s) - mu1*p2(s);
    S = dsolve(eqn1, eqn2, eqn3)
```

I get the following error:

```
Cannot reduce to the square system because the number of equations
differs from the number of indeterminates.
```

I believe it's got to do something with the parameters. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

**System of ODEs**

I think your system of differential equations is missing two odes. I have made some correction just on a guess to your actual system.

```
syms p0(s) p1(s) p2(s) lambda1 lambda2 mu1 mu2;

eqn1=diff(p0,s)-1==-lambda1*p0-lambda2*p0+mu1*lambda2*p0/(s+mu2)+mu2*lambda1*p0/(s+mu1)
eqn2=s*diff(p1,s)==lambda1*p0-mu2*p1;
eqn3=s*diff(p2,s)==lambda2*p0 - mu1*p2
```

Now using `dsolve` to find the solution to the above system

```
 S = dsolve(eqn1, eqn2, eqn3)
```

To access the solution, we can do something like this

```
solpo(s) = S.p0 
solp1(s) = S.p1 
solp2(s) = S.p2
```

or you can also assign the outputs to dependent variables

```
[poSol(s) p1Sol(s) p2Sol(s)] = dsolve(eqn1, eqn2, eqn3)
```

Is this what you were looking for?

**An ODE + two algebraic equations**

If you are planning to solve an ode and then sub that solution to the two algebraic equations, then

```
syms p0(s) p1(s) p2(s) lambda1 lambda2 mu1 mu2;
eqn1=diff(p0,s)-1==-lambda1*p0 lambda2*p0+mu1*lambda2*p0/(s+mu2)+mu2*lambda1*p0/(s+mu1);
[p0(s)] = dsolve(eqn1)
eqn2=subs(s*p1==lambda1*p0(s)-mu2*p1(s))
eqn3=subs(s*p2(s)==lambda2*p0(s) - mu1*p2(s))
```